# InputStreamReader doesn't read HTML code from some websites

Tags: java, html, inputstream, httpresponse

I use the following piece of code

```
if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == con.getResponseCode()) {
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("/n");
                }
                System.out.println(sb);
            }
```

to read HTML code from my connection. Code works just fine and gets the right thing on some websites, but other ones seem to have some kind of defence against this? Either way, I don't receive full HTML code of connection.
Here's an example of what should be printed out [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7MuM.png) vs what I get [actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHTCj.png).

Comment: May they just be sending you a redirect so that the response code is not HTTP_OK?

Comment: No, the responce code is 200.

Comment: You need to come up with examples. Many sites have anti-scraping protection, but there should be some kind of response. What happens exactly?

Comment: I added an example of what I expected/what I received.

Comment: `\n` is the escape sequence you're looking for, not /n, though you might want to find out the correct line separator for your platform with `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: Not all sites return a statically-rendered page—a lot of sites are updated dynamically after the first render. The days of scraping a complete page with a single request and no JS execution ended years ago. The “actual” response you link to a picture of text of appears to align with your expected response, though. Whitespace is (roughly) irrelevant in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Some web servers require you to specify a **user agent**, here you can find a list of them: https://user-agents.net/

You could try something like Firefox 100.0 on Windows 10 (64bit):

```
URL url = new URL(/* ... */);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0 Viewer/93.9.7218.19");
```